# Add fixed alert on the top of the page

Tags: css

I have a requirment that I want to show the alert on the top of the page if a particular event happens.

So I want to push the content of the page down and add it to the top. I tried using position: fixed it overlays the page.

My markup is something like this

```
<body>
... some html

<div>
    <div>Sticky alert</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Why not use Javascript and/or jQuery?

Comment: I can use jquery to append to the body top node but I want to use css, if possible, because on that page where I am its an angular JS app and I want to be able to use the angular functionality on that page

Comment: If you want to use AngularJS functionality, why not using something like `ngIf`, so that when a condition is `true`, you display a block on the top of the page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: because on main page anugular module is not added. Angular module is added on a seperate page

Comment: If you want it to push the content down by itself, then you want to insert it before the other body content in the DOM, and not position it absolute or fixed - because those two both take it out of normal layout flow. If you can’t do that, and need to position the element - then you will have to make the rest of the content move down yourself as well, for example by applying a matching padding-top to body, or something like that.

Comment: Then why do you need using Angular functionality if Angular is not loaded on that page? lol... I think based purely on CSS it can't be done, you need to evaluate the condition and the event happening through JavaScript at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using Position Sticky

```css
.message {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="message">Here is a message</div>
<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>
```

## Fixed Height Message

```css
.message {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

body {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="message">Here is a message</div>
<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>
```

Comment: I've added a solution for a fixed height bar. You can always set the values with JS if you need something more dynamic.